# BeautifulSoup split by <br>

Tags: python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup, split, tags

I'm trying to split a text by br tags.

I have this tag :

```html
<div class="grseq"><p class="tigrseq"><span id="id0-I."></span>Section I: Contracting authority</p><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.1)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Name and addresses</span><div style="color:black" class="txtmark">Official name: WOBA mbH Oranienburg<br>Postal address: Villacher Straße 2<br>Town: Oranienburg<br>NUTS code: <span class="nutsCode" title="Oberhavel">DE40A</span><br>Postal code: 16515<br>Country: Germany<br>E-mail: <a class="ojsmailto" href="mailto:kordecki@woba.de?subject=TED">kordecki@woba.de</a><p><b>Internet address(es): </b></p><p>Main address: <a class="ojshref" href="http://www.woba.de" target="_blank">www.woba.de</a></p></div><!--//txtmark end--></div><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.2)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Information about joint procurement</span></div><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.4)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Type of the contracting authority</span><div style="color:black" class="txtmark">Other type: Wohnungswirtschaft</div><!--//txtmark end--></div><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.5)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Main activity</span><div style="color:black" class="txtmark">Housing and community amenities</div><!--//txtmark end--></div></div>
```

I try to receive a list of each line like so:

```
['Official name: WOBA mbH Oranienburg', 'Postal address: Villacher Straße 2', ...]
```

This is my code:

```
webpage = 'https://ted.europa.eu/udl?uri=TED:NOTICE:565570-2019:TEXT:EN:HTML&src=0&tabId=0#id1-I.'
webpage_response = requests.get(webpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find(class_="mlioccur")
br_tags = tags.text.strip().split('\n\n')
print(br_tags)
```

What I recive is a list with one entry:

```
['I.1)Name and addressesOfficial name: WOBA mbH OranienburgPostal address: Villacher Straße 2Town: OranienburgNUTS code: DE40APostal code: 16515Country: GermanyE-mail: kordecki@woba.deInternet address(es): Main address: www.woba.de']
```

Would be greatful for any help :)

Comment: Good asked question. Here is the documentation of [BeautifulSoup's `get_text`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function. And here are similar questions: [extract text between line breaks (e.g. <br /> tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275359/using-beautifulsoup-to-extract-text-between-line-breaks-e-g-br-tags), [Extract text with line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53145500/extract-text-with-line-break-in-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `.get_text()` method with `separator=` parameter. And then `str.split()` according this separator:

```
txt = '''<div class="grseq"><p class="tigrseq"><span id="id0-I."></span>Section I: Contracting authority</p><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.1)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Name and addresses</span><div style="color:black" class="txtmark">Official name: WOBA mbH Oranienburg<br>Postal address: Villacher Straße 2<br>Town: Oranienburg<br>NUTS code: <span class="nutsCode" title="Oberhavel">DE40A</span><br>Postal code: 16515<br>Country: Germany<br>E-mail: <a class="ojsmailto" href="mailto:kordecki@woba.de?subject=TED">kordecki@woba.de</a><p><b>Internet address(es): </b></p><p>Main address: <a class="ojshref" href="http://www.woba.de" target="_blank">www.woba.de</a></p></div><!--//txtmark end--></div><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.2)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Information about joint procurement</span></div><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.4)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Type of the contracting authority</span><div style="color:black" class="txtmark">Other type: Wohnungswirtschaft</div><!--//txtmark end--></div><div class="mlioccur"><span style="color:black" class="nomark"><!--Non empty span 2-->I.5)</span><span class="timark" style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">Main activity</span><div style="color:black" class="txtmark">Housing and community amenities</div><!--//txtmark end--></div></div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

out = []
for tag in soup.select('.txtmark'):
    out.append(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))

out = '|'.join(out).replace(':|', ': ').split('|')

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Official name: WOBA mbH Oranienburg',
 'Postal address: Villacher Straße 2',
 'Town: Oranienburg',
 'NUTS code: DE40A',
 'Postal code: 16515',
 'Country: Germany',
 'E-mail: kordecki@woba.de',
 'Internet address(es): Main address: www.woba.de',
 'Other type: Wohnungswirtschaft',
 'Housing and community amenities']
```

Comment: Great solution: a real self-contained [example] without requests, but relying only on static HTML intpu `txt`. Some __comments documenting the solving changes__ in your code would be helpful.